# UIWebView to open string

Tags: ios, swift3, uiwebview

Im trying to make a `function` open a `string` through a `UIWebView` instead of quitting my app and opening safari.Although no mattar what i tried the app crashes...

## TemplateViewController;

## Here is my function:

```
let string = OnlineMenulinksTemplate
        if string.characters.count > 0, let url = URL(string: string), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            // valid URL
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
        }
```

## WebViewController:

```
import UIKit

class OpenWebViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!


 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    }
```

**So how would i tell the string to be opened and presented in that**`UIWebView`?

## thanks :)

Comment: What does your crash report say?

Comment: Well, removed what i tried cause it didn't work. here is the code that is working through safari, and i would like it to be presented by my `UIWebView`.

Comment: what is this `OnlineMenulinksTemplate` ?

Comment: its an `array` of links i converted into a `string`.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: I didn't find the specific solution im looking for yet

Comment: what is the issue with the one i have added?

Answer (score 0):

You should just create a URL request

```
let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a public function, lets say `loadWebView(with string: String)` on your webViewcontroller.

If the string is a valid URL, create a `URLRequest` instance and load it in your webview. Also, make sure your `webView` outlet is connected in the xib file or storyboard.

```
class OpenWebViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    func loadWebView(with string: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: string) else {
            print("Invalid string -> can not convert to URL")
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        //Force view to be loaded
        _ = self.view
        self.webView.loadRequest(request)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
let webViewController = OpenWebViewController()
webViewController.loadWebView(with: "http://google.com")
```

Google.com will be loaded in your webViewController.